# How to trap "The text is too long to be edited" error

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have an Access form bound to a backend SQL Server database.  When users enter text that exceeds the data limits for the respective data column that is bound to that form control, Access displays the "The text is too long to be edited" error.  I think (but haven't been able to verify) that this is error # 2221.

I'd like to be able to trap this error to have a more user-friendly message.  On researching (found [this](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/how-do-i-trap-error-the-text-is-too-long-to-be-edited.153238/) and [this](https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/1093520)), some coders mentioned being able to trap that error in the Form_Error event, and I found a support article with a decent example of using the Form_Error event to trap errors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.error).  But this doesn't work for me.  The Form_Error event doesn't seem to fire during this error, although it seems to have fired in the previously-referenced threads when they successfully trapped the error this way.  Someone in the threads mentioned that the error wasn't trappable before Access 2002, but is since Access 2002.  I have Access 365!

Any insight into whether this error is actually trappable, or how I might approach this either within the Form_Error event or otherwise?

Comment: Bing search led me to https://www.solvusoft.com/en/errors/runtime-errors/microsoft-corporation/microsoft-access/2221-the-text-is-too-long-to-be-edited/

Comment: Your links are almost always useful, but that Solvusoft page is garbage. Just some generic fluff and ads for their products. @June7

Comment: You already have evidence that the error is trappable. It's the indication of how obscure this error message is and that Access is not necessarily the source that I found interesting in that link. Frankly, couldn't find much. If we cannot reproduce as well as no code to analyze, question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I just remembered dealing with this issue long time ago, at least it seems same. I try to prevent an error instead of trapping whenever I can. I use code to test length of input to UNBOUND control before record is edited by SQL UPDATE action. Code is in button Click event. In your case, might be able to use control BeforeUpdate. Validate data before committing input, don't let user leave control until entry meets requirements.

Comment: And also just occurred to me, can use ValidationRule and ValidationText properties. Rule like: `Len([myControl])<=25 Or Is Null`.

Comment: FYI, I tested this with a simple new database that is bound to a local table, and same issue.  So this isn't limited to my situation where we are bound to a SQL Server table.  It's also very easy to replicate with a simple toy database with one table/one form.

Comment: Yes, I am confused. Could have sworn it worked in my earlier test but today not. I did not think to test copy/paste before and yes that definitely prompts the error. Other than possibly using a memo field or unbound textbox and using code in BeforeUpdate to check length, I have nothing else.

Comment: Er, where did my previous comments go?  Someone deleted them.

Comment: Do you mean the comments under my answer? I deleted my answer.

Comment: Just edited my answer and undeleted.

Comment: Finally read both referenced links in total which seem to be contradictory. And the second includes suggestions I offered in my answer. I also cannot get the Form_Error event code to work.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Sorry, forgot it was in response to your answer, and just thought things were disappearing.  Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 2):

The only 'otherwise' approach I can suggest is to prevent error instead of trapping. Normally, Text (short text) type field will prevent typing more characters than the allowed limit. However, this fails with pasted text and the referenced error is triggered.

To deal with pasted text that might be more than 255 characters, consider a memo (long text) field or an UNBOUND textbox. Use ValidationRule and/or VBA code to validate input - don't let user leave control until entry meets requirements.

I tested copy/paste and control's BeforeUpdate event was triggered.

A ValidationRule like `Len([myControl])=10 Or Is Null` on a memo field or UNBOUND control works with typed or pasted input.

Comment: The BeforeUpdate event approach was what we attempted first.  That approach didn't work.  We both couldn't trap this particular error there, and couldn't squeeze in any code to handle this issue before the error was triggered.  Seems the error is triggered before the BeforeUpdate event fires.

Also, there was a reason that using validation didn't work.  I'll test that again and report back on why that was (can't remember).  But I recall that the validation approach didn't work for us.

Comment: I verified that the validation approach does not work.  If I paste in a long bit of text (which is the primary way that people will enter data into this field), the "The text is too long" error triggers before the validation happens.  If someone _types_ in the data (which would almost never happen in our use case), then Access seems to just block them from typing more characters than the column can take, with no error message.  But even in that case you never get to the validation message.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: How did you test the BeforeUpdate?  We tried that and no error was detected.

Comment: No, it does not detect an error because there isn't one. Code is not looking for an error. it would test length of textbox value and if it is not acceptable, cancel the update and tell user to re-enter. This is data validation and exactly what BeforeUpdate event is meant for.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't work for us, because the error trips before any BeforeUpdate fires.  We never get to any BeforeUpdate coding at all, actually.

Comment: Then you are not using memo field or unbound textbox as suggested in answer.

Comment: Ah, thought those were multiple (separate) suggestions.  Yes, I'm aware that I could deal with this with an unbound textbox.  But my question was about how to trap the error, and/or if that was possible.

Comment: You also indicated openness to alternatives with 'otherwise'. I provided 'otherwise' since trapping was not working in spite of indications it should. Since you were already aware of these alternatives and rejected them, could have stated so in your question.